# How to pass parent model from inside partial view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

I am rendering a parital view which has a submit button with HttpPost action in controller. This action method needs parent model as its parameter. Is there any way to send parent model as first parameter from inside a partial view?

Main view -> aspx file which has model as ParentModel

Partial view -> ascx file which has model as ParentModel.ChildModel

Controller action -> MyActionName(ParentModel model, int direction, int user)

If I keep the method as HttpPost then by default Parent model gets passed but then I cannot send 2nd and 3rd parameter as their values are decided at run time and these are not childmodel properties. e.g. direction parameter which indicates if user has clicked next/prev button. In this case, next and prev buttons call same action method (MultipleAction submit)

Additional info: My parent model has a collection of child model. I am looping through this collection and calling RenderPartial for each item. So, I cannot pass this parent model directly to my partial view (which is default behavior).
Any suggestions please? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap all those partials into a HTML `<form>` so that all values get submitted too the server when this form is posted:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>

    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomePropertyOfParent) %>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeOtherPropertyOfParent) %>

    <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Children) %>

    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

I use an editor template instead of partials for the `Children` collection. The custom editor template will automatically be rendered for each element of this children collection and provide any input fields allowing to modify it.

Then when the form is finally submitted all the properties required by the model binder to reconstruct the `ParentModel` will be sent to the server. As far as the direction and user parameters are concerned I would make them part of the parent view model so that my POST controller action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyActionName(ParentViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Using EditorTemplate is a better option! no need to pass model to oartial view... thanks! You helped me second time today. :)

Comment: After I replaced RenderPartial with EditorFor, I found that now my form is not posting. I have used Multi submit on my aspx as I have multiple post buttons on ascx. When I looked at "view source ", I saw that the names of controls are changed. In case of partial view they were like model.prop[0].subprop and in case of editor template they are like model_0_subpro_ etc. Do I need to do any other setting to make it work with Editor templates?

Comment: @Anil Soman, normally if inside the template you use helpers such as TextBoxFor they should generate proper names of the input fields like  `model.prop[0].subprop`. `model_0_subpro_` is the id, not the name. As far as the model binder is concerned in the POST action it uses the name because this is what is sent to the server.

Comment: Yes you are right its a name.. For RenderPartial, it named it like model[0].prop[0].subprp[0] and for EditorTemplate it named it like subprop[0] only...
That could be the reason why it is not submitting properly?!